# Replace NaNs in dataframe with values from another dataframe based on two criteria

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, nan

Hi this is my first post to stackoverflow. I have been trying to solve this problem, but have not been able to figure out the answer alone nor find other posts that answer this question.

I need to replace missing values from my dataset with values from another dataframe; however, where it gets tricky is that the values I need to match have another factor associated with them, but matching dates.

Here is a simplified version of the first dataframe:

```
> df1
 date       site       Value  
 1991-07-08 A          22.5
 1991-07-09 A          NaN
 1992-07-13 B          23.1
 1992-07-14 A          NaN
 1993-07-07 B          27.3
```

Here is a simplified version of the second dataframe:

```
> df2
date       site         value
1991-07-08 A          22.5
1991-07-09 A           NaN
1992-07-14 A           NaN
1991-07-08 B          10.6
1992-07-09 B            23
1992-07-14 B           NaN
1992-07-09 C          11.3
1992-07-14 C          12.4
```

What I want to do is when there is a missing value for A to replace it with the value from B (with the same date), and if there is not value for B, using the value of C (with the same date). Thus, the resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
> dfFIN
date       site       Value  
1991-07-08 A          22.5
1991-07-09 A            23
1992-07-13 B          23.1
1992-07-14 A          12.4
1993-07-07 B          27.3
```

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
dfFIN<-replace(df1[which(df1$site=="A"),],
           df1$value[which(df$value=="NaN")],
           df2$value[which(df2$site=="B" &        
           df2$date==df1$date[which(df1$value=="NaN" & df1$site=="A")])])
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, list, value = numeric(0)) : 
    missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames
```

And I have not incorporated site C yet. I am not quite sure what to do and would appreciate any help.

Comment: You need to use `?is.nan` instead of trying `=="NaN"` - `NaN` is a special value representing infinite values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! First of all, your problem seems a bit underdefined, so I went ahead and made several alterations. I'm starting with two data frames:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
date       site       Value  
1991-07-08 A          22.5
1991-07-09 A          NaN
1992-07-13 B          23.1
1992-07-14 A          NaN
1993-07-07 B          27.3
", head = T)
df2 <- read.table(text = "
date       site         Value
1991-07-08 A          22.5
1991-07-09 A           NaN
1992-07-14 A           NaN
1991-07-08 B          10.6
1991-07-09 B            23
1992-07-14 B           NaN
1992-07-09 C          11.3
1992-07-14 C          12.4
", head = T)
```

Replacing `NaN` with a more traditional `NA`:

```
df1$Value[is.nan(df1$Value)] <- NA
df2$Value[is.nan(df2$Value)] <- NA
```

Merging (left joining) data frames that are cast from long to wide format (`reshape2`), so that date serves as a key:

```
library(reshape2)
dd1 <- dcast(df1, date ~ site)
dd2 <- dcast(df2, date ~ site)

dm <- merge(dd1, dd2, by = "date", all.x = TRUE, suffixes = c("", ".y"))
```

`dm` looks like so:

```
        date    A    B  A.y  B.y    C
1 1991-07-08 22.5   NA 22.5 10.6   NA
2 1991-07-09   NA   NA   NA 23.0   NA
3 1992-07-13   NA 23.1   NA   NA   NA
4 1992-07-14   NA   NA   NA   NA 12.4
5 1993-07-07   NA 27.3   NA   NA   NA
```

Now it is super easy to replace `NA` with anything you want without the need to bother with dates. I'm using the following rule: if `A` is missing, use `B.y`, if `B.y` is also missing, use `C`.

```
dm$A <- ifelse(is.na(dm$A), 
               ifelse(is.na(dm$B.y),
                      dm$C, dm$B.y), 
               dm$A)
```

Now restore the original format:

```
dfFin <- na.omit(melt(dm[, c("date", "A", "B")], id = "date", variable.name = "site"))

         date site value
1  1991-07-08    A  22.5
2  1991-07-09    A  23.0
4  1992-07-14    A  12.4
8  1992-07-13    B  23.1
10 1993-07-07    B  27.3
```

Comment: thank you @tonytonov To follow up, say I had more sites than ABC and each site would have different replacement sites, for example,

site A would be replaced by B than C;
site B would be replaced by C than D;
site E would be replaced by F than G.

How would I change the if else statement to be more general?

Comment: That would require something different than`ifelse`. I recommend you to ask another question which would refer to this one. You may drop a notification for me when it's done.